# Powershell Forloop with custom header

Tags: powershell, output

Desired output:

```
Server  Data1  Data2
------  -----  -----
Server1 Stuff1 Thing1
Server2 Stuff2 Thing2
Server3 Stuff3 Thing3
```

Question:

I have 3-4 different variables that I want in a custom table view with a custom header. The problem is that I use a ForEach and I'm not sure how to get it into a table view. Right now the best I can do is `Write-Host "$server $stuff $thing"` and that puts each one in a row. I tried to some magic with `@{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name"` but did not get anywhere.

The main point is that I have 3 vars at the end of the day and I need to get it into a custom table view.

```
$data = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")

while($true) {

    cls
    "`r"

    ForEach ($server in $data) {

        if (Test-Connection $server -count 1 -quiet) {

            net use r: \\$server\s$\Folder /user:server\administrator password >$null        
            r:

            $inputcount = (dir input -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count

            $forwardcount = (dir forward -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
            $forwardcount = ($forwardcount-2)
            if($fowardcount -lt 0) {
                $forwardcount = 0
            }

            if($inputcount -gt 0 -or $forwardcount -gt 0) {        
                if($inputcount -gt 5000 -or $forwardcount -gt 200) {        
                    $sleepless = "1"        
                }

                Write-Host "$server" -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline        
                Write-Host ": " -NoNewline        
                Write-Host "$inputcount" -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline        
                Write-Host " - " -NoNewline        
                Write-Host "$forwardcount" -ForegroundColor Red        

                $inputcount = ""        
                c: >$null        
                net use r: /Delete >$null
            } else {        
                Write-Host "$server" -NoNewline        
                Write-Host ": " -NoNewline        
                Write-Host "$inputcount" -NoNewline        
                Write-Host " - " -NoNewline        
                Write-Host "$forwardcount"        

                $inputcount = ""
                c: >$null        
                net use r: /Delete >$null
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question to show us the code you have now?

Comment: It does not matter much with the code I have, the point is that I am left over with 3 vars and I want to get them into a table view somehow, but I edited and added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a collection of [custom objects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750381.aspx):

```
"Server1", "Server2", "Server3" | ForEach-Object {

    # NB: Test-Connection "host" -Count 1 sometimes fails on an online host
    if(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $status = "online"
    } else {
        $status = "offline"
    }

    # PowerShell v3+
    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        Server = $_
        Status = $status
        Count = 20
        What = "ever"    
    }

    # PowerShell v2
    $item = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Server -Value $_
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $status
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Count  -Value 20
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name What   -Value "ever"
    $item
}
```

Returns:

```
Server  Status  Count What
------  ------  ----- ----
Server1 offline    20 ever
Server1 offline    20 ever
Server2 offline    20 ever
Server2 offline    20 ever
Server3 offline    20 ever
Server3 offline    20 ever
```

Comment: I guess the `-ea 0` is an abreviation for -ErrorEAction SilentlyContinue or similar. How to get the meaning of these numbers - is there a reference?

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to set the color of the vars to anything? So the Headers are all default but maybe one var be red, another blue, etc.

Comment: Display & colors: `Write-Host "string" -ForegroundColor "Cyan"`(poor). Data & structure: custom objects (rich). You *could* export data to HTML for formatting, for instance.

Comment: `-EA 0` means `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, correct. I don't find a reference for the index number right now. I'll replace the shorthand in my snippet for clarity.

Comment: [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = Write-Host "$server" -ForegroundColor "Red"
        Input = $inputcount
        Forward = $forwardcount
        }  

does not seem to work

Comment: You **cannot** mix both methods. You really should forget about `Write-Host`. If you really want to use it, you will have to simulate the table with tabulations but this will be ugly.

Comment: Yes I can just write-host it all, but if any number is larger than expected, the output is weird/not formatted correctly.

Comment: @LotPings: got it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20878.error-action-preference-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Ty, thats a valuable reference, especially for one liners.

Comment: Is there any way to output the heading by itself, then the rows of data separate? That may be the solution to my problem.

Comment: I guess so, simply output the heading before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @sodawillow but if you do that, the output in each column might not line up if the values get larger/smaller. any advice?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to have colored tables in the PowerShell console.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general format I would use. The `foreach` is completely incorrect as I don't know how you're going from one row of data to the next; whatever it is, loop over that.

Bare in mind this is destructive; `+=` deletes the previous array and creates a new one. However it tends to be my goto when dealing with small data sets because of simplicity and readability.

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    [array]$tableVariable += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Server = $server
        Data1  = $stuff
        Data3  = $thing
    }
}
```